# Custom Taglib Compilation error

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, taglib

I am trying to create a taglib for my custom tag. But I am getting a compilation error in Eclipse IDE. Here is my TagLib description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>  
  <uri>MyFunction</uri>
  <function>
      <name>myFunc</name>
      <function-class>com.tldcls.MyClass</function-class>
      <function-signature>int age()</function-signature>
  </function> 
</taglib>
```

I am getting a compilation error on the  tag. The error tells:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'uri'.
```

I am not able to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: Please use text for text, not images; thanks.

Comment: Its not getting displayed properly, hence given that image. For your convenience, i am editing it again.

Comment: Just read the message formatting rules in the message editor. You've posted 33 questions, surely you should already know how to format code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XSD mentioned in the file (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd) reveals that the taglib element has the following child elements, in this order

- `tlib-version`
- `short-name`
- `uri`
- ...

The `short-name` is not optional, and it's supposed to be the suggested prefix to use for this taglib.

Comment: I had there an ordering problem, putting uri before

Answer (score 0):

There is a XSD version error.

You can use
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd".

Answer (score 0):

The schema's definition for uri points to an "anyURI" type,

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#anyURI

This refers to the XLink href attribute which in turn refers to RFC 2396 which in turn says that URIs look as follows,

```
<scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>
```